# Using onclick event to submit 2 parameters into a the same servlet

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets

I'm trying to use a submit button to pass 2  parameters, `userId` and `friendId`, using jsp into the same servlet. I am able to obtain `friendId`, however, I am not able to obtain the `userId`.

```
function anotherPageServlet(servletName) {

    document.forms[0].method = "post";
    document.forms[0].action = servletName;
    document.forms[0].submit();
}

function anotherPageServlet1(servletName) {

    document.forms[0].method = "post";
    document.forms[0].action = servletName;
    document.forms[0].submit();
}

<input style="color:#3333ff" 
       type="submit" 
       class="rsubmit" 
       value="<%= retrieving.getDisplayname()%> :" 
       onclick="anotherPageServlet('ViewingFriendServlet?stringParameter=<%= session.getAttribute("userId") %>'),
anotherPageServlet1('ViewingFriendServlet?stringParameter=<%=retrieving.getoID() %>')"
>
```

Comment: Is there a special reason you're having two identical JS functions?

Comment: @Hubert Grzeskowiak there is no reason for that. My main motive to pass the 2 parameters, userId and friendId together to the servlet.

Answer (score 0):

You probably only need to escape the quotes:

```
onclick="anotherPageServlet('ViewingFriendServlet?stringParameter=<%= session.getAttribute(\"userId\") %>'),
anotherPageServlet1('ViewingFriendServlet?stringParameter=<%=retrieving.getoID() %>')"
```

I'm not used to JSP, but in JSF you would rather assign values to a request-scoped bean and then call a function that works with that bean, rather than passing those arguments directly.

**EDIT:**

Define onclick functions first, then call only the simple reference.

```
function servletFoo() { 
    anotherPageServlet('ViewingFriendServlet?stringParameter=<%= session.getAttribute("userId") %>');
    anotherPageServlet1('ViewingFriendServlet?stringParameter=<%=retrieving.getoID() %>');
}
```

Then in your HTML:

```
<input ... onclick="servletFoo()" />
```

Comment: Sorry, there is some syntax error. Is there any other way to pass these to value at the same time to servlet?

Comment: sorry for the syntax error. can't test it here. you might want to define the JS functions in the script block and pass only the newly created function to onclick. This way you have one level less of nested strings. See updated answer